# Google Apps Spreadheet SUMPRODUCT issue

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with the headings

Status | Currency | Total

In the rows I have a variation of statuses and currencies.

Using Google Spreadsheet I added this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Complete"),(B1:B10="GBP"),C1:C10)
```

in the hope calculating the total sum of those rows which are COMPLETE and GBP

The error I get is

```
#VALUE!
Range has no entry corresponding to this cell
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can you the following formulas.

### Formula

`=SUM(FILTER(C1:C10,A1:A10="Complete";B1:B10="GBP"))`

OR

`=QUERY(A:C;"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE B='GBP' AND A='Complete'")`

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[SUMPRODUCT issue](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3cVshJOjtvTQCGArwFlJJLAw3xaU9sL7WCeR3IdFY4/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem - but am using 'New' Google Sheets and the reason seems to be that in 'Old' SUMPRODUCT required array entry. So the fix should have been:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Complete"),(B1:B10="GBP"),C1:C10))
```

That is, enter or re-enter the formula **as in OP** but with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[Ref: [Yogi Anand](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/_wWyC8nfIYY)]